# SQL Server 2005 trigger to update remote server

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers, msdtc

I have created a trigger that updates an remote SQL Server 2005 database table. The code works if it is a manual query but will not work in a trigger because it tries to place it in a transaction and fails because of MSDTC.

Our internal server has appropriate access to the remote server but the remote server does not have access to the internal server, would this cause the trigger to fail?

The error I get is:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LinkServer" returned
>   message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions.".  Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
>   "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LinkServer" was unable to begin a
>   distributed transaction.

I have looked this up and set everything as suggested but no joy?

Answer (score 1):

And what if the remote server is unavailable for any reason?

You should generally avoid performing any action in a trigger that works beyond the *database*, let alone the *server*. The issue is that everything that happens within the trigger *has* to be part of the original transaction, and if anything goes wrong in the trigger, that transaction will be rolled back.

You do not, usually, want this to happen if there's an intermittent problem reaching a remote resource (be that a different DB on the same server/instance, or something truly remote).

Have you looked into decoupling this activity with, for instance, [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: Ok this makes sense and I agree a trigger is not the best way to go, I have a dates table that we input dates and I need this to update our website DB server so is a service broker the best way to go?

Comment: @LukeWilkinson - it's what I'd generally recommend - unless the tables in the source and destination databases are identical in terms of structure and data - in which case I'd be looking at [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.90).aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have some tight deadlines so what I did this time is a trigger that starts a job that calls a stored procedure and that works, probably not recommended but serves by requirments.